# Java - How can I easily parse XML with XML Pull Parser?

Tags: java, android

I searched a lot about XML Parsers and found out the Pull Parser would be the best for Android Applications. So I searched for some easy examples to understand but I didn't found one. Can somebody help me and say how you can easily parse XML with Pull Parser (from a URL not assets)?

Thank you :)

Comment: If I Google your question right now do you think I will find answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the below link download the sample demo project it will parse the stackoverflow RSS feed

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/index.html

Answer (score 0):

you can find all about **XML Pull Parsing** here

http://www.cafeconleche.org/slides/sd2002east/xmlpull/XML_Pull_Parsing.html